# doc.jquery.com api documentation

Tags: jquery, api, documentation

I read that [docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com) uses wiki to do the API documentation. I have been searching, but I can't find which wiki system did they're using.

Does anyone know about this, because I want to write an API documentation in a similar way that [docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com) did it.

I did hear that wikiMedia is easy, but haven't got a clue if I should use that.. I just want it to be easy to do it and have the same formatting as the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery documentation at http://docs.jquery.com uses [MediaWiki](http://mediawiki.org), the same system used by Wikipedia and other wikis in the Wikimedia network. There are some minor visual elements that the jQuery docs and Wikipedia share (such as the icon next to external links). You can also find references to MediaWiki in the source code.

As for themes, formatting and so on, I can't really help in that — I haven't really used MediaWiki myself.

Note that http://docs.jquery.com and http://api.jquery.com are separate sections. Only the former is powered by MediaWiki; if I'm not wrong the latter runs on a custom-made system.